# Checking if fields in form are filled in

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I have a form with textboxes, dropdownlist etc. If something is updated by pressing the save button I create a note e.g. if the user changes the name of the country.

```
if (cust.CountryName.ToString() != ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text)
{
    Customer.Notes.InsertNote(cust.ID, Company.Current.CompanyID, DateTime.Now, "Country changed from '" + cust.CountryName + "' to '" + ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text + "'", CurrentUser.UserID, 1);
}
```

A note is created saying what was changed, by which user and the date and time.

I have a lot of similar if statements for different fields in the form, but I want to create a note for all the fields that don't need a special note. For some fields I just want to create a note like:

```
Customer.Notes.InsertNote(cust.ID, Company.Current.CompanyID, DateTime.Now, "Customer updated" , CurrentUser.UserID, 1);
```

It doesn't matter what exactly was changed. I just want to know the customer form was updated.

Is there a way to check the other fields in the form without creating a separate if statement for each field? Basically if something is updated and its not any of the if statements, create the note "Customer updated". So when the save button is pressed it runs all these if statements, checking if any changes were made.

Comment: You could tie all of your changed events to one all-encompassing ValueChanged Event

Comment: but some changes have certain notes for them, but all the rest I want just "Customer updated" note created.

Comment: Then only tie the events you want a general note for to the "ValueChanged" event? Unless you aren't using events to trigger this in the first place?

Comment: the notes are created when a saved button is clicked. So I'm not using events. When the save button is clicked it runs all the if statements to check if anything has changed

Comment: Then you are using an event (save button, although it doesn't help a ton for this scenario..). If you don't have any other events, you'll have to check everything individually. At the very least, I would recommend creating a general changed Event for what you want to write the general note for (either triggering the note creator directly or setting a property to check later). Otherwise you'll be checking in your if statements.

Comment: I'm just using a try catch in the save function. All the if statements are in the try. I don't want to just create the note "Customer updated" every time something is changed. I need to run all the if statements and if something else that is not one of the if statements is updated, then create note

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85443/discussion-between-dangerzone-and-user123456789).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We came up with an answer to this particular situation in [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85443/discussion-between-dangerzone-and-user123456789). The desired behavior was to write the general note if none of the if statements were triggered.

Add a property to track the changes of the fields:

```
public bool HasChanges { get; set; }
```

Add a line in each existing `if` to set this to true since a property has changed (from the original post):

```
if (cust.CountryName.ToString() != ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text)
{
    Customer.Notes.InsertNote(cust.ID, Company.Current.CompanyID, DateTime.Now, "Country changed from '" + cust.CountryName + "' to '" + ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text + "'", CurrentUser.UserID, 1);
    HasChanges = true;
}
```

And add a last if statement to write the general note if the other `if` statement have not been triggered.

```
if (!HasChanges)
{
    //Write general note
}
```